# useSWR get called even when not needed

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch, swr

I have created a SWR fetch to get some data and memoize it with useMemo on page A, but when I navigate to page B, C or D, I can still get the console.log "fetch call".
Is that normal?
Why is it going to make a call to the database even when is not defined on page B, C and D?

```
  export const useFetchAccount = () => {
  const token = getToken();

  const fetcher = (url) =>
    fetch(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Token ${token}` } })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .finally(console.log("fetch call"));

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}${URL}`, fetcher);

  const userData = useMemo(() => {
    if (!data) {
      return [];
    }
    console.log("fetch account");

    return data;
  }, [data]);

  return { userData, isLoading };
};
```

Comment: What is URL, in the first parameter of useSWR?

Comment: you mean `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}${URL}`?
is the base url pointing to the database

Comment: I am not sure why it logs that text every time. But I see few mistates. .finally(() => console.log(...)) is the correct syntax, not .finally(console.log(...)). The first argument in useSWR should be something unique for each request. It is the key where it stores the cache, It can not store all the cache in single key, it should change for each different endpoint. Fixing some of them might resolve your problem

Comment: ok thanks for the help. however, the endpoint it is always the same.

Comment: It calls the fetcher again because `swr` considers your data stale and it wants to refetch it. You can use `import useSWRImmutable from 'swr/immutable'` if you want to fetch just once and never refetch after